# XML to HTML converstion

Tags: html, xml

My requirement is by reading xml file i need to build html page  is there any opensource available to accomplish this requirement . Presently i am reading all xml field tags and printing on jsp by using cforeach.

Comment: Sounds like a job for [XSLT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XSLT)

Comment: i think you can use this link http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/12047/How-to-Convert-XML-Files-to-HTML

Answer (score 2):

As XML is a general markup language you need a translation/mapping for the entities in your XML on HTML. This can be done with XSL [1] and here [2] is how.

[1] http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XSL_Transformation

[2] http://www.htmlgoodies.com/beyond/xml/converting-xml-to-html-using-xsl.html

Answer (score 0):

As vanthorne suggests, XSLT is the  way to go.  There's a decent "getting started" tutorial on W3Schools.

http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/xsl_intro.asp

You can do your transformation client side, or most scripting languages have a means of doing it server side, but if you're using JSP already, here's a JSTL example.  For this to work you'll need jstl.jar and xalan.jar in your WEB-INF/lib folder

```
<c:import url="http://your.rssfeed.url" var="xmldocument" charEncoding="utf-8" />
<c:import url="rssnewsfeed.xsl" var="xslt" charEncoding="utf-8" />
<x:transform xml="${xmldocument}" xslt="${xslt}"/>
```